# Why is MEF in dotnet 6 using ImportManynot working based on code that worked in dotnet framework 4.6.2

Tags: .net-core, mef

I am converting code from dotnetframework to a dotnet6 WPF Hybrid app, and use MEF.  The compose show the plugin and metdata in the container but neither collection via [ImportMany] have any contents.  I get no exceptions.  The plugins do load in a DotnetFramework app.  has anyone any ideas on getting ImportMany to work?

```
public class PluginHandler
[ImportMany(typeof(IKapprisWebViewerClientPlugin))]
        private static IEnumerable<Lazy<IKapprisWebViewerClientPlugin, IKapprisWebViewerClientPluginData>>? plugins { get; set; } = new 
List<Lazy<IKapprisWebViewerClientPlugin, IKapprisWebViewerClientPluginData>>();

        [ImportMany(typeof(IKapprisWebViewerClientPlugin))]
        private static IEnumerable<IKapprisWebViewerClientPlugin>? plugins1 { get; set; } = new List<IKapprisWebViewerClientPlugin>();

 public PluginHandler()
        {
            //An aggregate catalog that combines multiple catalogs
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

            string exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string directory = new Uri(Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath)).LocalPath;

            //Adds all the parts found in all assemblies in 
            //the same directory as the executing program
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(
             new DirectoryCatalog(
              directory, "kwc*.dll"));

            //Create the CompositionContainer with the parts in the catalog
            CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            //Fill the imports of this object
            container.ComposeParts(this);
            //container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);

        }
}
```

the plugin class

```
    [Export(typeof(IKapprisWebViewerClientPlugin))]
    [ExportMetadata("Name", "IManage 10 / Cloud")]
    public class WebViewerIntegration : WebViewerClientPlugin
    {
     ...
    }

 public interface IKapprisWebViewerClientPluginData
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Name used to identify plugin
        /// </summary>
        string Name { get; }
    }
```

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. I'm not sure if MEF was ported to .NET Core, it's certainly not needed to provide dependency injection. .NET Core's own DI is far simpler and more powerful.

Comment: It is not for providing DI its providing the loading of plugins, as the directory catalog scans dll's for the interface and does not have to know what is there before hand.  Also many items can have the same interface and the metadata associated with the class allows me to pick the correct class via the MEF functionallity.  I have not found that Microsoft DI really allows that that well.

Comment: So the real question is how to load arbitrary plugins from disk. Check [Create a .NET Core application with plugins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support). MEF wasn't ported to .NET Core because many of its features became part of the platform, others were greatly simplified and others changed completely, including AppDomain and assembly loading.